# Scilab xcos values linking to gui(or guibuilder code)

Tags: scilab, xcos

I have a problem that i can't solve. Please help me out.
The problem is i can't find any scilab codes to link my xcos values to a real time slider and change it as the gui is running. For you to imagine it easier i linked my pc screen with the code and xcos model :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyeL4.jpg
I would like to look my gui(on the left) like that and add a graph which the CMSCOPE values in it, as xcos shows. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to use the TKSCALE block (type help TKSCALE at Scilab prompt).